# Template in C++ Error only on long Datatype

Tags: c++

I am a newbie in C++ , can someone help me with this Error?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T1>
int findElement(T1 field[],T1 element,long int indx);

template<typename T2>
double getAverage(T2 field[],long int indx);
int main()
{
       int arr1[] = {1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,3};
  long int arr2[] = {19133,15133,13213};
    double arr3[] = {1,1,1,2.9,0,0,0,0};

  findElement(arr1,2,sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int));
  cout << "Average =" << getAverage(arr1,sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int)) << endl;
  findElement(arr2,15133,sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(long int)); //<=== Error
  cout << "Average =" << getAverage(arr2,sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(long int)) << endl;
  findElement(arr3,2.9,sizeof(arr3)/sizeof(double));
  cout << "Average ="  << getAverage(arr3,sizeof(arr3)/sizeof(double)) << endl;
  return 0;
}

template<typename T1>
int findElement(T1 field[],T1 element,long int indx)
{
      int pos = -1;
  cout << " searching for " << element << " ...";
  for(int i=0;i<indx;i++)
  {
      if(element==field[i])
      {
          pos = i;
      }
   }
   if(pos>0) cout << " found! Position is : " << pos << endl;
   else      cout << " no found!" << endl;
   return pos;
}

template<typename T2>
double getAverage(T2 field[],long int indx)
{
   int sum = 0;
   for(int i=0;i<indx;i++)
       sum += field[i];
   return static_cast<double>(sum)/static_cast<double>(indx);
}
```

> |19|error: no >matching function for call to ‘findElement(long int [3], int, long >  >unsigned int)’|
>   note: candidate: >template int findElement(T1*, T1, long int)|
>   note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
>   /home/robin/Dokumente/CPP/Labor2/Aufg2/aufg2b/main.cpp|19|note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘T1’ (‘long int’ and ‘int’)|
>   ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that

```
template<typename T1>
int findElement(T1 field[],T1 element,long int indx);
```

Requires `field` and `element` to have the same type.  When you call

```
findElement(arr2,15133,sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(long int));
```

`arr2` is a `long` but `15133` as a integer literal with type `int`.  since `long` and `int` are not the same type template argument deduction fails and you get a compiler error.  Do note that the compiler so no conversions during template argument deduction.  If the types do not match during that step then the template will not be used.

You can fix it by making `15133` a `long` integer literal like

```
findElement(arr2,15133L,sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(long int));
                      ^ L for long
```

Comment: @RobinOwelov No problem.  Glad to help.